# How to pass multiple selected checkbox from one page to another?

Tags: php

How to pass multiple selected checkbox from one page to another? I am a beginner, sorry for that. Thank you in advance for those who'll help me out with this problem.

Comment: you can do with `php` or `ajax` choice is your

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data from one page to another through :

- SESSION
- COOKIE
- GET and POST

```html
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="value1">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

***page2.php***

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<select>
<option value="value1" <?php if($_POST['var1'] == 'value1'){ ?><?php selected ?>>value1</option>    
<option value="value1" <?php if($_POST['var1'] == 'value2'){ ?><?php selected ?>>value2</option>
<option value="value1" <?php if($_POST['var1'] == 'value3'){ ?><?php selected ?>>value3</option>
</select>
```